# Start vino-server (VNC) before login on Linux CentOS

Tags: centos, gnome, vnc

I'm using the default vino-server package to access my CentOS 6 workstation via VNC.

It works ok, but only AFTER I locally login on the workstation. I need to have vino-server start BEFORE the login, right at the Gnome login screen where I choose username and password.

Due to personal reasons, **I need to use Vino and not vnc-server or any other packages**.

I already tried to insert `/usr/libexec/vino-server &` in `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` but this didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Create the desktop file that's going to start **vino**:

```
# cat > /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/vino-server.desktop << 'EOF'
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Remote Desktop
Comment=GNOME Remote Desktop Server
Exec=/usr/libexec/vino-server
Icon=preferences-desktop-remote-desktop
Terminal=false
Type=Application
EOF
```

Change some of the **vino**'s settings<sup>1</sup> for the **gdm** user (**vino** runs under it):

```
# su -s /bin/sh -l gdm -c               \
     'gconftool-2 --set --type=bool     \
                  /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true'
# su -s /bin/sh -l gdm -c               \
     'gconftool-2 --set --type=bool     \
                  /desktop/gnome/remote_access/prompt_enabled false'
```

Note that *all you can do is login*. After the user logins, the VNC sesssion ends. At the end of the session, you'll be able to reconnect to GDM.

You'll also need to [disable SELinux](http://stopdisablingselinux.com/)<sup>2</sup> or preferable write the required rules to let user **gdm** run **vino-server**.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I got the details from an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/22354/74792) to "Enable remote VNC from the commandline?" from the Ask Ubuntu SE.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Modify `/etc/selinux/config` so that `SELINUX=permissive` or use [**setenforce**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setenforce.8.html).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Based on Cristian's answer, this seems to work on more recent Gnome versions:

```
# cat > /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/vino-server.desktop << 'EOF'
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Remote Desktop
Comment=GNOME Remote Desktop Server
Exec=/usr/libexec/vino-server
Icon=preferences-desktop-remote-desktop
Terminal=false
Type=Application
EOF
```

Logout any session and make sure you are at GDM login screen, then execute following commands via SSH or VT1,2,3,... :

```
# su -s /bin/bash - gdm
$ export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus" 
$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['screen-cast', 'remote-desktop']"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
```